# Google Cloud Function NPM

Tags: node.js, json, npm, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use a google cloud function to turn a 3d model into an image. My function won't deploy. I have tried to use ypm install and npm install in the package file.

Deployment failure:

```
Build failed: npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
     npm ERR! file /workspace/package.json
     npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json`
     npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token n in JSON at position 120 while parsing near '...rage": " 
     ^1.6.0"
     npm ERR! JSON.parse npm install"craster"...'
     npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
     npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Package.json is

```
{
  "name": "sample-cloud-storage",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^1.6.0"
    npm install"craster": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have `npm install` where it is. Should look like

```
{
   "name":"sample-cloud-storage",
   "version":"0.0.1",
   "dependencies":{
      "@google-cloud/storage":"^1.6.0",
      "craster":"^3.1.5"
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, did you manage to make it work due to the missing comma? or you missed the coma only in the post?

Comment: I've just deployed with this answer and it works as a charm. **removing - npm install** and ***removing the comma**